# The tens and hundreds aren't being printed out. How to do this?

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, numbers, cpu-word

This is my code:

```
digit = input("Enter a number to convert to words: ")

units = {
        1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three", 4:"four", 5:"five", 6:"six", 7:"seven", 8:"eight", 9:"nine",  10:"ten", 11:"eleven", 12:"twelve", 13:"thirteen", 14:"fourteen", 15:"fifteen", 16:"sixteen", 17:"seventeen",
         18:"eighteen",19:"nineteen"}
         
tens =  {

         20:"twenty", 30:"thirty", 40:"fourty", 50:"fifty", 60:"sixty", 70:"seventy", 
         80:"eight", 90:"ninety"}
         
hundred = { 100:"one hundred", 200:"two hundred"
            }

def number_to_words(problem):

    if len(digit) <= 2 and int(digit) in units.keys():
        
         print(units[int(digit)])
            
    elif len(digit) == 2:
            
        split_number = []

        for letters in digit:
            split_number.append(letters)

        if len(split_number) == 2:
            
            first_letter = split_number[0] + '0'
            second_letter = split_number[1]

        for num in tens.keys():
            first_letter = int(first_letter)
            if first_letter == num:
                global split_tens
                split_tens = tens[first_letter]

        for num in units.keys():
            second_letter = int(second_letter)
            if second_letter == num:
                global split_unit
                split_unit = units[second_letter]

        print(split_tens,'-', split_unit)

        
    if len(digit) == 3:
        split_number = []

        for letters in digit:
            split_number.append(letters)
        
        if len(split_number) == 3:
            first_letter = split_number[0] + "00" 
            second_letter = split_number[1] + "0"
            third_letter = split_number[2]
            # print(first_letter, second_letter, third_letter)

        for num in split_number:
            first_letter = int(first_letter)
            second_letter = int(second_letter)
            # if split_number[1] == int(0):
            #     second_letter = "and"
            third_letter = int(third_letter)
            if first_letter == hundred.keys():
                pass
            if second_letter == tens.keys():
                pass
            if third_letter == units.keys():
                pass
        print(hundred[first_letter], "and", tens[second_letter], units[third_letter])

number_to_words(digit)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

You're only working with up to 3-digit numbers so you only really need your units and tens dictionaries.

Even aside from that, you are really over-complicating your code. Some obvious issues:

- No need to loop over `digit` and save to a list. Since `digit` is a string, you can be index it.

  - As an aside, if you need to save each character of a string to a list, you can simply use `split_number = list(digit)`

- `units` and `tens` are `dict`. No need to loop over them to match on the key. This defeats the purpose of using dictionaries.

Try something like this:

```
units = {1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three", 4:"four", 5:"five", 
         6:"six", 7:"seven", 8:"eight", 9:"nine",  10:"ten", 
         11:"eleven", 12:"twelve", 13:"thirteen", 14:"fourteen", 15:"fifteen", 
         16:"sixteen", 17:"seventeen", 18:"eighteen",19:"nineteen"}
         
tens =  {20:"twenty", 30:"thirty", 40:"fourty", 50:"fifty", 60:"sixty", 70:"seventy", 80:"eighty", 90:"ninety"}

def number_to_words(digit):
    if int(digit) in units.keys():
         name = units[int(digit)]
    
    elif int(digit) in tens.keys():
         name = tens[int(digit)]

    elif len(digit) == 2:
        name = tens[int(digit[0]+'0')]+"-"+units[int(digit[-1])]
        
    elif len(digit) == 3:
        if int(digit[1:]) == 0:
            name = units[int(digit[0])]+ " hundred"
        elif int(digit[1:]) in units.keys():
            name = units[int(digit[0])]+ " hundred and " + units[int(digit[1:])]
        elif int(digit[1:]) in tens.keys():
            name = units[int(digit[0])]+ " hundred and " + tens[int(digit[1:])]
        else:
            name = units[int(digit[0])]+ " hundred and " + tens[int(digit[1]+'0')]+"-"+units[int(digit[-1])]
    return name

>>> number_to_words("456")
'four hundred and fifty-six'

>>> number_to_words("78")
'seventy-eight'

>>> number_to_words("820")
'eight hundred and twenty'
```

##### Edit:

It would be much cleaner to use recursion like so:

```
roots = {1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three", 4:"four", 5:"five", 
         6:"six", 7:"seven", 8:"eight", 9:"nine",  10:"ten", 
         11:"eleven", 12:"twelve", 13:"thirteen", 14:"fourteen", 15:"fifteen", 
         16:"sixteen", 17:"seventeen", 18:"eighteen",19:"nineteen", 20:"twenty", 
         30:"thirty", 40:"fourty", 50:"fifty", 60:"sixty", 70:"seventy", 80:"eighty", 90:"ninety"}

def number_to_words(digit):
    if int(digit) in roots.keys():
         return roots[int(digit)]
    
    elif len(digit) == 2:
        return roots[int(digit[0]+'0')]+"-"+number_to_words(digit[-1])
        
    elif len(digit) == 3:
        if int(digit[1:]) == 0:
            return roots[int(digit[0])]+ " hundred"
        else:
            return (roots[int(digit[0])]+ " hundred and "+number_to_words(digit[1:]))
    return None
```

Comment: It works better thanks, but now i can't print out digits with "0" a the ends. For example: 10, 20, 100, 300 etc. @not_speshal

Comment: Works fine but feel it could be simplified further - maybe? Recursive way?

Comment: Yes. I initially used recursion but seeing OP's question and code, I figured, the simpler the better.

Comment: I get this error when i try numbers that aren't units or end with zeros. 

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object.

I am trying to figure out why though, because the code reads correctly.

Comment: @Preshh0 - Cannot reproduce. I printed every number from 1 to 999 and it works. That is what this was designed to do as in your question